# Cast type parameters must be Dynamic

Tags: casting, haxe, openfl

I just started using `haxe(moving from AS3)`.

I'm trying to cast to Array, but it doesn't work, namely I get `Cast type parameters must be Dynamic` error when I try to compile. Below is the code I use:

```
    var result: Array<String> = cast(["sometext"], Array<String>);        

    var arr: Array<Int> = new Array<Int>();
    arr.push(1);
    var vect : Array<Int> = cast(arr, Array<Int>);

    var arr1: Array<Int> = [1, 2 ,3];
    var vect1 : Array<Int> = cast(arr1, Array<Int>);

    var arr2 = [1, 2 ,3];
    var vect2 : Array<Int> = cast(arr2, Array<Int>);
```

Each of these 4 casts doesn't compile and gives the same error "Cast type parameters must be Dynamic". If I change the type parameter to Dynamic it won't work either. It fails with a different error.

Could someone explain why this way of casting is not working and how I can cast to Array?

Other casts:

```
    var i: Int = 1;
    var j: Int = cast(i, Int);

    var str: String = "str";
    var str1: String = cast(str, String);

    var instance: CastToArrayTest = new CastToArrayTest();
    var instance1: CastToArrayTest = cast(instance, CastToArrayTest);
```

Work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's perhaps easier to explain with some sample code:

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        var a = ["foo", "bar"];
        $type(a);  // Warning : Array<String>

        // no need to cast or type simple assignments
        var b = a;
        $type(b);  // Warning : Array<String>

        // but lets define `x` as `Dynamic` (or something that we don't know what it is)
        var x:Dynamic = ["foo", "bar"];
        $type(x); // Warning: Dynamic

        // we can simply assign it to an `Array<Dynamic>` variable (but we don't get any runtime checks!)
        var c:Array<Dynamic> = x;
        $type(c);  // Warning: Array<Dynamic>

        // we can also simply assign it to an `Array<String>` variable (but we don't runtime checks either!!)
        var d:Array<String> = x;
        $type(d);  // Warning: Array<String>

        // (if we want runtime checks, we need to code them with the `Type` apis)

        // now, let's say we want to do
        //     var e:Array<String> = c;
        // but that fails with `Type parameters are invariant`...
        // we can instead use an unsafe cast
        var e:Array<String> = cast c;
        $type(e);  // Warning: Array<String>

        // type parameters are a compile time only feature
        trace(showType(a), showType([1,2]));
        trace(Std.is(a, Array), Std.is([1,2], Array));
        // safe casts only check the current object (not its children), so we need to use them with `Dynamic` parameters
        var f = cast(x, Array<Dynamic>);
        $type(f);  // Warning: Array<Dynamic>
        // however, due to variance, we can't assign a the safe cast result of type `Array<Dynamic` to a `Array<String>` variable without an unsafe cast...
        // which makes sense: our safe cast only checks that the object is an array, but the array doesn't know its own type nor has the safe cast checked the types of the children
    }

    static function showType(v:Dynamic)
    {
        switch Type.typeof(v) {
        case TClass(cl):
            return Type.getClassName(cl);
        case other:  // TODO handle other types
            return Std.string(other);
        }
    }
}
```

You can play with this live at [Try Haxe #CCaD5](http://try.haxe.org/#CCaD5).

---

Putting in another way, here's how your "cast" examples would usually work and look like:

```
var result: Array<String> = cast ["sometext"];

var arr: Array<Int> = new Array<Int>();
arr.push(1);
var vect : Array<Int> = arr;

var arr1: Array<Int> = [1, 2 ,3];
var vect1 = arr1;

var arr2 = [1, 2 ,3];
var vect2 = arr2;

var i: Int = 1;
var j: Int = i;
var k = j;

var str: String = "str";
var str1: String = str;
var str2 = str1;

var instance: CastToArrayTest = new CastToArrayTest();
var instance1: CastToArrayTest = instance;
var instance2 = instance1;
```

You can see this live (with some additional info) at [Try Haxe #97ADc](http://try.haxe.org/#97ADc).

Comment: First of all, thank you soo much for the answer. 
I understand your point, but still I think being not able to do a safe cast like this:  var arr1: Array<Int> = [1, 2 ,3];  var vect1 : Array<Int> = cast(arr1, Array<Int>); is a shortcoming of haxe. You can do it in other languages, AS3, Typescript, etc. When you convert a as3 code in haxe/openFL you would normally convert the casts in aforementioned way and you'll fail. Nevertheless, again, thanks a lot, it seems I must use unsafe cast when I want to cast arrays.

Comment: @CikaRaki I see your point too.  I would add: (a) to safely cast (at runtime) `something` to `Array<A>` it really would be necessary to check not only that `something` is an `Array`, but that all its elements are also of type `A`; (b) allowing type parameters to be variant all the time would cause many hard to debug issues ([it is intrinsically unsafe if modifications are allowed](https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-variance.html)); (b) you don't need any cast or conversion whatsoever for `var vect1 = arr1` (or `var vect1:Array<Int> = arr1`), as long as `arr1` is of type `Array<Int>` as well.